Logistic Regression on German Credit data from UC Irvine
I am trying to learn the logistic regression and encountered the German credit data set (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/144/statlog+german+credit+data). My query is - how to formulate  regression equation when categorical feature checking_status has 4 possible values:
'< 0' (col 1)
'0<X<200' (col 2)
'>=200' (col 3)
'no checking' (col 4)
in 4 separate columns?
Simple way is to treat each column as separate predictor and run the regression. But is it correct to do so? In other words, is there a logic for treating each column as separate or combine them in some way and treat the attribute as one? Thanks

